# Horizontally center fluid div containing elements set to float left

Tags: css

I've successfully centred an inner div in a parent div but the elements contained in the inner div are not horizontally in line.

For my approach see [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/SdeMV/9/embedded/result/).

I'm aware of the two most common apprroaches with centering a div in a div i.e. using HTML below:

HTML:

```
<div id="outer" style="width:100%">  
<div id="inner">Foo foo</div>
```

Centering method 1:

```
#inner {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Centering method 2:

```
#outer {
    text-align: center;
}

#inner {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Correct me if I'm wrong but:

- Method 1 seems suitable if the inner div is to have a set width.
- Method 2 seems suitable if the width of the inner div is fluid and say
  contains only one element as multiple elements aren't horizontally in line.

EDIT:

What I describe in method two above is the issue I'm having i.e. rather than the outcome as seen in my demo this is what I'm trying to achieve.

```
                            <<  <  March - 2016  >  >>
```

I'm looking for the best way to remedy this whilst making sure the width of the centred div is dynamic.

Comment: What do you mean from "horizontally in line" ?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour: Sorry if my earlier post was unclear. I've made edits which should help in understanding what I meant by horizontally in line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply align the inner elements as you did with the outer ones? What's the issue?

```
#calendarmonthcontrols > div, #calendarmonthcontrols > a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Ah .. thanks a lot .. it works .. I should have tough of that immediately .. clearly i have a lot to learn ..

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `inline-block`, that will position the elements in center.

Working example:
Updated [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/SdeMV/10/)

```css
  /* Wrapper div. That makes the inner div into an inline element that can be centered with text-align.*/
  #calendaroverallcontrols {
      text-align: center;
  }
  /* This is a fluid div as width will be changing */
  #calendarmonthcontrols {
      display: inline-block;
  }
  #btnPrevYr {
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 35px;
  }
  #btnPrev {
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 35px;
      margin-left: 20px;
  }
  #monthandyear {
      vertical-align: bottom;
      padding:0 10px;
  }
  #btnNext {
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 35px;
      margin-right: 20px;
  }
  #btnNextYr {
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 35px;
  }
  #calendarmonthcontrols a {
      position:relative;
      top:10px;
  }
  #calendarmonthcontrols a, 
                #calendarmonthcontrols div {
      display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<div id="calendaroverallcontrols">
    <!-- <div id="year"></div> -->
    <div id="calendarmonthcontrols"> <a id="btnPrevYr" href="#" title="btnPrevYr"><span><<</span></a>
 <a id="btnPrev" href="#" title="btnPrev"><span><</span></a>

        <!-- <input type="button" src="images/btnprevmonth.png" alt="Submit" id="btnPrev"/>-->
        <!-- <div id="month"></div>-->
        <div id="monthandyear">MARCH - 2015</div>
        <!--<input type="button" src="images/btnnextmonth.png" alt="Submit" id="btnNext"/>--> <a id="btnNext" href="#" title="btnNext"><span>></span></a>
 <a id="btnNextYr" href="#" title="btnNextYr"><span>>></span></a> 
    </div>
</div>
```